# Using POST in App Inventor

Tags: android, json, post, header, app-inventor

I am new to App Inventor. I am making a frontend of app with user login function. I got an api link and need to input mobile and password and post it to get a token. I tried postman and succeeded to get a token:
[image]

but in App Inventor I don't know how to input mobile and password, I am trying this, but failed:
[image]

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What is the response code and response content you are getting in the GotText event? You might want to edit your question and add that information... Also you might want to use the `BuildRequestData` block, see an example here how to do it: https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php